# Can the following series be divergent for arbitrarily large values of $s$?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, reference-request

Let $\{a_n\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$, $a_n>0$ be some sequence of positive reals. (Edit: Also, assume $a_n$ limits to infinity. My mistake for not including this earlier!)

Is it possible that the series
$$
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (a_n)^{-s}
$$
is divergent for arbitrarily large values of $s>0$ ? (I.e., for every positive real $c>0$ there is some $s\geq c$ for which the above series diverges.)

Would anyone know a reference which discusses this scenario?

---

Edit: I should have said that $a_n$ should limit to infinity; my apologies for the confusion!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Examples were given in other answers, however, I think it's worth noting that even if we require $a_n \to \infty$ we can still find an example of such a series. Taking $a_n=\log{n}$ for $n \geq 2$ we get that
$$\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}\frac{1}{\log^s{n}}$$
diverges for every $s \geq 1$. This can verified easily by [Cauchy's condensation test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_condensation_test).

Comment: Thank you for your explanation!

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is possible: take $a_n=1.$

Comment: My mistake, I should have said in my question that I'm assuming the $a_n$ limit to infinity.

Answer (score -1):

I claim that if $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n^{-r}$ converges for some $r>0$, then $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n^{-s}$ converges for all $s>r$. Take $N$ such that $a_n>1$ for all $n\geq N$; then $a_n^s>a_n^r$, $a_n^{-s}<a_n^{-r}$, and
$$\begin{align*}\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n^{-s}&=\sum_{n=1}^{N-1}a_n^{-s}+\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n^{-s} \\
&<\sum_{n=1}^{N-1}a_n^{-s}+\sum_{n=N}^\infty a_n^{-r} \\
&<\infty.\end{align*}$$
Thus the only possible such sequence $(a_n)_{n=1}^\infty$ would be one for which
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n^{-s}$$
diverges for *every* $s>0$. Giorgos Giapitzakis's answer gives an example of this.

Comment: Why the downvote?